# How to limit view movement in onTouch to a parentview in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

This seems to be easy to state but there seems no straight forward implementation. I want to limit the movement of an imageview to its direct parent. I couldn't find examples related to this. Can somebody help me with an example for this? 
I actually want to achieve a motion where the leaf in middle is moved, the leaf at the top should move to bottom and the bottom leaf should move to the middle and the middle leaf should move to top position. This coupled with the elevation of the middle leaf. Please refer to the image below.
I have tried to achieve this by using the rect of the parent view in onTouch of the view but that doesn't seem to work. Tried to achieve this listview and recyclerview but that seems to add a lot of complexity to a simple requirement.

[image]

Here is my code

```
public class Main6Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView;
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;
View view;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);


     view = findViewById(R.id.imglayout);
   final Rect rect = new Rect(view.getLeft(),view.getTop(),view.getRight(),view.getBottom());
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
            if(event.getAction() ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                if(isViewContains(X,Y)){
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });


}
private boolean isViewContains(int rx,int ry) {
    int[] l = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(l);
    Rect rect1 = new Rect(l[0], l[1], l[0] + view.getWidth(), l[1] + imageView.getHeight());
    return rect1.contains(rx, ry);
 }
}
```